# How do you duplicate current open Finder view?

Tags: macos, shortcuts, finder

I often have a window where i want to drag and drop to a parent folder, and i need another finder window, so i open a new one and need to browse back to where the other window is ...

Comment: This thread's unnecessary struggle is classic Apple. So... it's 2022, and there's no way to duplicate a Finder window, just like there's no calculator on the iPad.

Answer (score 14):

most similar thing:

1. go up one level
2. CMD + double-click the folder

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: This requires ensuring Finder Preferences has "Open folders in tabs instead of new windows" unchecked in the General tab. This workaround seems to be the closest thing to an answer available.

Answer (score 9):

> One solution is, you do Show Path Bar (view menu), then hold Command
>   and double click on the icon in the path bar that represents the
>   current folder.

This works.

Taken from: http://forums.appleinsider.com/showthread.php?t=106205

Comment: mouse right click open new window.

Comment: This does not appear to work in 12.6.

Answer (score 5):

1. open a new window.
2. choose "Go -> Go to folder..." or hit Cmd-Shift-G.
3. drag the proxy icon from the first window (the little icon that appears in the title bar) to the location field in the second window.
4. hit return.

Comment: Doesn't work in 10.5, but it works in 10.6.

Answer (score 4):

This applescript works for me (Snow Leopard 10.6.7)

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate --probably not really necessary
    set currentfolder to target of window 1
    set clonedwindow to make new Finder window to currentfolder
end tell
```

This will open a new window showing the same folder as the current frontmost window. You can then attach this to a keyboard shortcut with Quicksilver or something.

Comment: Works in macOS Big Sur 11.6.4, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The simplest shortcut to duplicate an open window in OS X:

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

If you are in list or icons view and have something selected in the folder, just go up to the parent folder, then select the folder you want to open in more than one window, and click the shortcut.

If you click it one more time right after, it will open another copy of the window you just opened.

It will also work if you are viewing a window in icons or list view mode with no files or folders selected in it, or with a folder selected in columns view mode (will open another window with the same view/folder selected). So instead of navigating up using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, you could also hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to switch to columns view, then <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to open the folder you are viewing in another window.

Answer (score 1):

With your Parent window open (I prefer Columns View) just drag the main folder (the one that contains most of the files you want to transfer to the new window) into the sidebar on the left > under PLACES. This will create a temporary folder alias in all of your windows, in the same place.

So it's not a quick key but now you can just hit <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and only have to click the new sidebar folder.  Saves time.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the Finder replacement "Path Finder" interesting. It allows you to open a second pane with the click a button (they call it a "Dual Pane File Browser"). It also has a little clipboard area that you can temporarily pin files to while you navigate from window to window.

See http://cocoatech.com

Lots of other cool features - eg the ability to show invisible files, open a CLI at the current path... etc

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to execute menu commands while dragging a file. Otherwise, `Ctrl-Cmd-Up` would be what you want (press `Ctrl` and look in the *Go* menu).

I tried creating a *Service* using Automator that performs a similar action, but that cannot be started while dragging either.

---

<sub>For reference, remember, it didn't work as I hoped:</sub>

```
tell application "Finder"
    set topWnds to every window whose index is equal to 1 as list
    set topWnd to first item of topWnds
    set cwd to target of topWnd as alias
    reveal cwd
end tell
```