# Open new Finder tab when using 'open .' in the Terminal

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, finder, osx-mavericks

In the Terminal I use `open .` to open the current directory using Finder.

`Open folders in new tabs` settings is set in the Finder, yet it opens a new window every time. By the end of a project/day I have dozens of these windows open.

How do I get the Finder to open a new tab, instead of a new window when using `open .` in the Terminal?

Comment: I don't think `open` can handle that for the moment.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106131/make-folders-opened-by-external-apps-open-in-a-new-finder-tab-rather-than-a-wind

Comment: Perhaps, some AppleScript hacking could resolve this problem. (sorry, I don't have Mavericks to test it, but you can try to adapt the solution [here](http://blog.qsapp.com/post/66560143350/opening-folders-in-finder-tabs)).

Comment: ...and hack your shell to replace the default "open ." behaviour with this applescript launch.

Answer (score 4):

Probably a bit late, but in case other people are still searching for this.
In macOS Big Sur this works: System preferences > General > Prefer tabs > select `always` from the dropdown menu.

Now `open .` will open in a new tab in an existing Finder window. It also works from iTerm.

Comment: People are still looking and thanks for adding that bit :)

Comment: on macOS Ventura: System Settings > Desktop & Dock > Windows & Apps > Prefer tabs when opening documents > Always

Comment: While having **Preferences > Desktop & Dock > Automatically hide and show the menu bar** set to on Finder still would not open in a tab. I figured out you also have to set **Finder > Settings > General > Open folders in tabs instead of new windows** to on as well. This made `open .` open the current Finder window and open `.` in a new tab in that window.  (in Ventura)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `open .` to open a new tab in Finder, though it is possible to open a new tab using AppleScript - from [How do you duplicate current open Finder view in new tab (Mavericks)?](https://superuser.com/questions/666762/how-do-you-duplicate-current-open-finder-view-in-new-tab-mavericks)

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set t to target of Finder window 1
    set toolbar visible of window 1 to true
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "t" using command down
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    set target of Finder window 1 to t
end tell
```

Alternatively from http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=41624

```
set docs_path to (path to documents folder) as string
set Sat_folder to docs_path & "Sat:"
set ABC_folder to (Sat_folder & "ABC:") as alias

tell application "Finder"
   activate
   open Sat_folder
end tell

tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down

tell application "Finder"
   set target of front window to ABC_folder
end tell
```